# I am unable to use npm install again on my windows 10

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, node-modules

[image]

I have tried a lot of solutions online, but I could not solved this issue. Even if I format my laptop to get rid of this issue, I'm still getting this error. Please help. I have attached an image for the error. Thanks

Comment: Did you try running cmd/Powershell as admin?

Comment: Yes. I can't work with npm

Comment: Maybe you can permission for create directories.

Comment: When in doubt, I always try to use folders without spaces in them. Your user account folder has a space in it, which is probably a bad idea.